# Use of "From where" and "Where from"

Tags: sentence-construction, prepositions, questions

I'm a little confused about which of the following sentence is correct. If both of them are correct, then when to use each of these?

> 1. From where have you done your Bachelors?
> 2. Where have you done your Bachelors from?

Comment: I would never say any of those. I'd just say: "Where did you do / get your Bacherlor's Degree". I would not use "from" with "do", do not being a verb expressing movement. You could use "from" with "get": "Where did you get your Bacherlor's Degreee from?". As to the place of the preposition it's quite common in questions to reject it at the end of the question.

Comment: I think what PO wanted to ask is missed in the answers here because of another problem in the example sentence, and it's answered here: https://www.quora.com/Which-is-the-correct-sentence-%E2%80%9Cfrom-where-did-you-get-this-%E2%80%9D-or-%E2%80%9Cwhere-did-you-get-this-from-%E2%80%9D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Do from* is an ‘Indianism’, so use of this phrase must be referred to speakers of that dialect.

In Standard English<sup>†</sup> we use *at* with the verb *do*; the preposition phrase names the place where the work was performed:

> I did my doctorate at the University of Wisconsin.
>   He did an internship at Microsoft.

We use *from* in this context with *receive*; the preposition phrase names the entity which  conferred the gift:

> I received my doctorate from the University of Wisconsin.

In ordinary speech, however, we use the verb *get*, which may take either preposition phrase (though *at* is probably more common)

> I got my bachelors at Vanderbilt.
>   I got my bachelors from Vanderbilt.

With *do* we use *at*;

In a question, no preposition at all is needed, whichever verb you use:

> Where did you do your bachelors?
>   Where did you get your bachelors?
>   Where did you receive your bachelors?

---

<sup>†</sup>By “Standard English” I mean English usage which will pass unnoticed with any educated native speaker—appropriate to its register and not dialectal, foreign, antiquated, or precious.

Comment: Very good definition of standard English suitable for ELL where I think we have a responsibility towards those ESL students who rely on the answers.

Comment: @Stoney, should "bachelors" not be capitalized and/or have an apostrophe? I'm fairly certain you have quite a bit more experience with such things than I do, but I find it reads oddly. For one thing, reading some of these sentences makes me imagine a group of actual bachelors (the people, that is). Obviously context would clear that up, even in the single sentence in some of the examples. But I find this strange. Thoughts? (+1, by the way; excellent answer!)

Comment: WendiKidd Usage varies. It seems to be rarely capitalized any more, except in the formal Bachelor of X. Most schools refer to it as "bachelor's degree". But I'm uncomfortable with a possessive unattended by a possession; and the possessive never made any sense to me anyway--if we were being rational about it it should be "bachelor degree". So since it's a colloquial rather than formal expression I feel free to treat it as what it is, a singular noun which happens to end in {s}.

Comment: @WendiKidd - More about the capitalization/apostrophe questions can be found on ELU. Start [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140648/when-should-the-word-masters-or-bachelors-be-capitalized-with-apostrophe).