# Which one is correct?

Tags: tense

At present, I`ve been doing MBA in Human Resource Management (HRM) at DU

or

At present, I am doing MBA in Human Resource Management (HRM) at DU

Answer (score 4):

Neither is correct.  "MBA" is not something you "do".  Here are some better options:

- I am currently working on an MBA in Human Resource Management (HRM) at DU.
- At present, I am studying toward an MBA in Human Resource Management (HRM) at DU.
- I am currently studying toward an MBA in Human Resource Management (HRM) at DU.
- I am in DU's MBA program.  My MBA will be in Human Resource Management (HRM).
- Recently, I've been studying Human Resource Management (HRM) at DU.  I'm in DU's MBA program.
- I am pursuing an MBA... I am enrolled in the HR MBA program at DU.  *(mc01's suggestion.)*

Comment: I am pursuing an MBA...
I am enrolled in the HR MBA program at DU

Comment: Once you've got it, however, an MBA **is** something you *did*!

Comment: @StoneyB Why would you say that? It makes no sense grammatically to claim that something can't be *done* in the present but could in the past. *MBA* is the name of the degree (not the program or coursework), so it's incorrect to say *I did an MBA*; you would say *I got an MBA*.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName Perhaps MBAs speak differently (most of the ones I work with do, anyway); but I did my doctorate at Wisconsin.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17085/use-of-from-where-and-where-from/17096#17096 It seems valid that you *do* degrees.

Comment: @StoneyB does it mean *Where did you **do** your bachelors* incorrect? http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17085/use-of-from-where-and-where-from/17096#17096

Comment: It's too common in India to use it this way. The bitter fact is we use it in this way **only**. It seems it's okay with natives as well. *My women friends included a Japanese theology student, an Irishwoman ***doing bachelors*** in Zoology who came from a strict Catholic family* from [this page](http://archives.dailynews.lk/2005/07/12/fea10.htm) probably written by a professor at the University.

Comment: @Maulik It's perfectly correct in circles I move in, but it apparently sounds odd to Esoteric. And "I'm doing a bachelor's at Wisconsin" sounds odd to me. Idiolect? Dialect? I don't know.

Comment: Doubtless the discrepancy comes from differences of region, or possibly even academic field. It does not sound odd to me to say *I did my undergrad*, as I read *undergrad* as short for *undergraduate coursework*. I agree with @StoneyB that *I did my bachelor's* isn't standard.

Comment: @StoneyB You are right. MBA is something *I* ***did*** is all okay. Found an entry (160.2) in Swan's PEU. It says - *We use 'do' when we talk about work and jobs.* The example further reads... *"I did **(=studied)** French and German at school."*

Comment: @EsotericScreenName when you have *studied* something, you can certainly use the verb *do* for that. Swan's PEU has an etry for that. See my comment to StoneyB up here.

Answer (score 2):

The second one is more correct.

One should usually keep the verb tense of sentences consistent.  Either of these would be more usually heard from a native speaker, however.

> Recently, I've been **pursuing** an MBA in ...

or

> At present, I'm **pursuing** my MBA in ...

Also, an MBA isn't something one typically 'does.'

One could also be 'studing for', 'going for', 'working on' or 'working toward' one's MBA.  I'm certain there are others, but 'doing' isn't usually heard.

Answer (score 1):

The first one contradicts itself, 'I've' is *I have* abbreviated, so it contradicts the first two words. The second one makes more sense but it doesn't sound fully right because as the people above have been saying you don't 'do it'.

So my advice would be:

> I am currently studying for a MBA in Human Resource Management (HRM) at DU.