# From where are/come you?

Tags: grammar, grammar-myths

Is "From where are you" and "Where from are you" as correct as "Where are you from"?

Or do you think one of those is more correct than the other?

I'm aware of the non-existant rule about ending a sentence with a preposition, but I need additional grammar explanations to know if I really get any subtleties.

In my opinion "Where are you from" is the most common, and the most correct, and the "From where are you" could be an hypercorrection, but I don't know if it's as correct.

Note, there's another thread with a title that could make think that it answers this question, but it use "done", so it's not the same case.
"From where have you done your Bachelors?"
[Use of "From where" and "Where from"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17085/use-of-from-where-and-where-from)

Comment: Yes, "Where are you from?" or "Where do you come from?" are the most idiomatic. "Where from are you" doesn't work at all. "From where are you?" is possible, but sounds very old-fashioned. The really archaic version would be "Whence came you?"

Answer (score 1):

I think your analysis is correct.  "Where are you from" is the correct syntax. "From where are you" is not idiomatic, and could be a hypercorrection. Don't use this word order.  "Where from are you" is simply incorrect grammar and a mistake.

It might be possible to use "From where" with other verbs.

> From where did you buy your hat?
>
> From which country does he come?

These seem a little odd, but neither is incorrect. The first is redundant to "Where did you buy your hat" and second is equivalent to "Which country does he come from?", but sounds a little more formal.